# When upload ios app i get Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, flutter

i get issue when upload ios app to app store :

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We were still unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone
- OS version: iOS 16.5

Next Steps

To address the crash in your app, follow these steps:

1. Fully symbolicate the crash report. See Adding Identifiable Symbol Names to a Crash Report for an explanation of the symbolication process.
2. Match the crash report to a common pattern. Based on the pattern, take specific actions to further investigate the crash. See Identifying the Cause of Common Crashes.
3. Test your app on a device to ensure that it now runs as expected.
4. Once you’ve addressed the crash, create and submit a new build to the App Store for review.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Their feedback is straightforward. Your app crashed while they were reviewing your application. My suggestion would be test your release build on simulator with iOS 16.5 or iPhone with iOS 16.5, resolve the issue and resubmit the application.

Comment: Test a TestFlight  build on a real device. Test with no network. Test on an ipv6 network. Look at the crash log they sent you.